# Django custom methods in templates and DB queries

Tags: python, django

I have a simple model to show Companies opening times

```
class Company(Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Empresa")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Empresas")
        ordering = ('published_dt',)

    user = ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name=_(u"Responsável"), null=True, blank=True)
    category = ForeignKey(CompanyCategory, verbose_name=_(u"Categoria"), help_text=_(u"Categoria que a empresa faz parte. Eg:. Alimentação, Pet Shop"), null=True, blank=True)

    # Company Fields
    title = CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_(u"Nome da Empresa"), null=True, blank=True)
    slogan = CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_(u"Slogan"), help_text=_(u"Um slogan ou descrição curta. Ex:. 'Compramos sua moto e pagamos á vista'"), null=True, blank=True)
    image = ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='uploaded_images')
    crop = CharField(choices=CROP, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Cortar Imagem"), help_text=_(u"Selecione o ponto de referência para cortarmos a imagem."))
    email = EmailField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Email"), null=True, blank=True)
    website = URLField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Website"), null=True, blank=True)
    published = BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_(u"Publicado"))
    published_dt = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now(), help_text=_(u"Date of publication - Not necessary to complete if you do not know what it is."), verbose_name=_(u"Published Date"))
    description = HTMLField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Descrição"), help_text=_(u"Uma descrição da sua empresa em poucas linhas."))

    enable_comments = BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_(u"Habilitar Comentários"))
    # Admin fields
    slug = SlugField(verbose_name=_(u'Slug / URL'), blank=True, null=True, max_length=300,)
    order = PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_(u"Ordem"), null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title

    def get_address(self):
        if self.address and self.city and self.number and self.uf:
            return u'%s, %s - %s, %s' % (self.address, self.number, self.city, self.uf)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        code = codifica(self.pk)
        return reverse('website:company_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'pk':self.pk})

class OpeningHours(Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Horário de Abertura")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Horários de Abertura")
        unique_together = ('company', 'weekday')

    company = ForeignKey(Company, related_name="opening_times", verbose_name=_(u"Empresa"))
    weekday = IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, verbose_name=_(u"Dia da Semana"))
    fromHour = TimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Abre ás:"), null=True, blank=True)
    toHour = TimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Fecha ás:"), null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s (%s - %s)" % (self.company, self.weekday, self.fromHour, self.toHour)
```

And I need a way to have something like `{{ company.is_open }}` on my template, and `Company.objects.all().order_by('open')`. How can I do that using my structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method to Company:

```
import datetime

...

class Company(Model):

    ...

    def is_open(self):
        today_hours = self.opening_times.filter(weekday=datetime.datetime.today().weekday())[0] # you may want to add code to make sure that there is an entry for this weekday
        if datetime.datetime.now().time() > today_hours.fromHour and datetime.datetime.now().time() < today_hours.toHour:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

You will then be able to call this using `{{ company.is_open }}` in your templates.

Unfortunately, you will not be able to query on this or order by it in your database calls. However, you can sort it after the query is done:

```
companies = sorted(Company.objects.all(), key=lambda c: c.is_open(), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Looks like this comparison are not working very well "if datetime.datetime.now() > today_hours.fromHour and datetime.datetime.now() < today_hours.toHour: " I'm trying to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Changed that line to add .time().  Try it now?  You might still have timezone issues.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm using the "food_companies      = sorted(Company.objects.filter(category__where_eat=True)[0:5], key=lambda c: c.show_open())" just like that, but it's ordering inverse.

Comment: You mean it's putting closed companies before open ones, right? You can reverse that by adding reverse=True to the sorted() call. I edited to do so.

Comment: The companies are still showing as closed even when it's open. Take a look at full code: https://dpaste.de/1JL2

Comment: Looks like that we have a trouble with the midnight because it's 00

Comment: Link isn't working.  But maybe you can just subtract 1 second from the fromHour and toHour before you compare them with the current time?